# How to validate parameters coming in the request body

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm working on a api for my college assignment where me and two of my friends have to make a rather complex app. I know that there are a lot of things that can be done better, but it's not the point of the question. I have the following code for registering a new user:

```
app.MapPost("/register", async (RegistrationInput inp, ThreeMoronsContext db) =>
{
    var HashingResult = PasswordMegaHasher.HashPass(inp.password);
    try
    {
        User UserToRegister = new()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Login = inp.login,
            Password = HashingResult.hashpass,
            Salt = HashingResult.salt.ToString(),
            Name = inp.name,
            Surname = inp.surname,
            Patronymic = inp.patronymic,
            UserClassId = inp.UserClassId
        };
        await db.Users.AddAsync(UserToRegister);
        //await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.Ok(UserToRegister);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return TypedResults.BadRequest(exc.Message);
    }
});
```

ThreeMoronsContext is the DbContext that comes from EntityFrameworkCore.
The RegistrationInput is:

```
    public record RegistrationInput(string login, string password, string name, string surname, string patronymic, int UserClassId)
```

I want to apply some validation to RegistrationInput, so that for example Login is between 5 and 20 characters long, the Name only cointains cyrillic letters and so on.
I've tried applying [StringLength] and [RegularExpression], but i feel like i completely missunderstood the purpose of such attributes, since when i tried, for example, this input:

```
 "login": "s",
 "password": "hashme123",
 "name": "123",
 "surname": "s",
 "patronymic": "ss",
 "UserClassId": 1
```

i got a 200 response with a new user being being created:

```
{
  "id": "caf3796e-ba8d-4583-8c43-e69020a03353",
  "name": "123",
  "surname": "s",
  "patronymic": "ss",
  "login": "s",
  "password": "q6anLJxltC2Wf7443xRjwbOxCLZ5SXT9LdtSDOVceRk=",
  "userClassId": 1,
  "groups": [],
  "userClass": null,
  "salt": "System.Byte[]"
}
```

What should i do to apply validation to data coming from request body?

Comment: Check out [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/). It can be setup in a way that validation-implementations are automatically applied/checked during model-binding eg. your endpoint won't even be hit if the validation doesn't pass.

Comment: Oh my god yes, this is exactly what i was looking for. Tysm

Answer (score 0):

Follow my code :-

RegistrationInput.cs file (Model):-

```
public class RegistrationInput
{
 [Required]
 public string login { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public string password { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public string name { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public string surname { get; set; }
 public string patronymic { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public int UserClassId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :-

```
app.MapPost("/register", async (RegistrationInput inp, ThreeMoronsContext db) =>
 {
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return Results.BadRequest(ModelState);
}

var HashingResult = PasswordMegaHasher.HashPass(inp.password);
try
{
    User UserToRegister = new()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Login = inp.login,
        Password = HashingResult.hashpass,
        Salt = HashingResult.salt.ToString(),
        Name = inp.name,
        Surname = inp.surname,
        Patronymic = inp.patronymic,
        UserClassId = inp.UserClassId
    };
    await db.Users.AddAsync(UserToRegister);
    //await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Results.Ok(UserToRegister);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    return TypedResults.BadRequest(exc.Message);
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**